# It it okay to manual test web applications?

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, tdd

I am learning TDD and trying to write tests following best practices in my projects. Generally, I write frontend in React and while learning, I found a great post on testing using react-testing-library by Robin [here](https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-testing-library).
I will be using the examples from Robin's site but other examples I have found in the web are similar as well.
So, one of the components that Searches on user input looks like:

```
function Search({ value, onChange, children }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor="search">{children}</label>
      <input
        id="search"
        type="text"
        value={value}
        onChange={onChange}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

A typical test case for this looks like:

```
describe('Search', () => {
  test('calls the onChange callback handler', () => {
    const onChange = jest.fn();

    render(
      <Search value="" onChange={onChange}>
        Search:
      </Search>
    );

    fireEvent.change(screen.getByRole('textbox'), {
      target: { value: 'JavaScript' },
    });

    expect(onChange).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

My questions:

1. Can't we just manually test this (or similar scenarios)?
2. Isn't it easy and intuitive to go on the browser and test whether the component is working as it is supposed to, by few clicks and inputs?

The only downside I have in my mind is that to replicate the test, I have to make few clicks again.

It feels like an overkill to mock apis, callbacks, etc just to verify that a component renders it after certain user action.

Surely, I am missing something here. Any clarification is highly appreciated.

Comment: Sure, if you just have one component it's easy enough to test manually. But what if you have ten, or a hundred, or a thousand, or... What if there are multiple user roles, with lots of different workflows and possible states? What if you're asked to make a change that touches some of those existing components, or even do something seemingly simple like upgrade a dependency; how confident are you that everything works afterwards?

Comment: "The only downside I have in my mind is that to replicate the test, I have to make few clicks again" - that's correct, pretty much like a robot. Incidentally, this is what test *automation* is for. "It feels like an overkill to mock apis, callbacks, etc just to verify that a component renders it after certain user action" - it's not an overkill if you need to spend hours to debug which apis, callbacks etc made your test fail. Even more if you cannot reproduce the problem to debug it.

Comment: Yeah, I guess over time it will be easier to manage the project.

Answer (score 1):

Everything has advantages and disadvantages.
Advantages of TDD (Behavior-driven development, unit testing, integrations tests) are the following:

- You will have to write clean code. I mean your methods/functions will be small and will do only one thing. You will have to keep [cyclomatic complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) very low to make your tests small, every control structure requires testing (ifs, switches..). You will avoid [side effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) in the methods.
- You will be able to refactor the code, because refactoring a code without tests is like a [changing one shit with another one](http://hamletdarcy.blogspot.com/2009/06/forgotten-refactorings.html).
- It will be good for team and for huge projects, you cannot know all the code. Any change in code can break the functionality, any bug fix can produce several other bugs. TDD helps us.

...

...

Disadvantages:

- you will have to write tests.. more code.
- you will have to think more before you write.
- in changeable projects you will have to change not only code but also tests

...

...

Comment: *you will have to think more before you write* -- that seems like a positive to me!

Comment: I am agree with you, but sometimes management and business need fast solutions ;)

Answer (score 0):

In general, manual testing is not really feasible for larger applications, or in the long run. Imagine a situation in which a core developer leaves the team and no one knows what should be tested manually.

There are tools which can do blackbox testing and automate browser clicks for you. A nice tool to start with is good old [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev). It's available for several languages, you may begin with the WebDriver version.